# Colaboratory で関数定義したグラフが表示されない

Tags: python, python3, google-colaboratory

Jupyter Notebook で実行していた内容なのですが、Colaboratory で実行したらグラフが出てこなくなってしまいました。

どこを修正すればいいのか、お分かりの方、いらっしゃいましたら、教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

```
import matplotlib

def jp_us():
    year = [1950, 1980, 2000, 2015, 2016]
    japan = [82, 116, 126, 127, 126]
    usa = [158, 230, 283, 322, 324]
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(year, japan, color='#FF0000', label='japan')
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(year, usa, color='#00FF00', label='usa')
    matplotlib.pyplot.legend()
    
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Python はあまり詳しくないですが、関数を "定義" しているだけで、"呼び出し" がされていないからではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます、やってみます。

Answer (score 1):

もしこれがプログラムの全てなのであれば、関数が定義されているだけで呼び出されておらず、したがって関数の中身が実行されていません。関数を呼び出してあげてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。調べながら、「呼び出すということ」をやってみます。

Answer (score 0):

defブロック以降はインデント削除し、jp_us関数の呼び出しを追加する。

```
jp_us  #jp_us関数の呼び出し 
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(year, japan, color='#FF0000', label='japan')
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(year, usa, color='#00FF00', label='usa')
matplotlib.pyplot.legend()
    
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```